# How to set my name for a particular repository in egit in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I noticed that after pushing some changes to my github clone of a project, I realized from the commit history that my user name is my email address name, which isn't the name that I'd like to be known as in that repository.  How do I change the name that's used only for that repository (or for anything that I clone from github)?

I'm using eGit in Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the command-line interface, this would change the name for a particular repository:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git config user.name "Full Name"
```

This stores it in the `.git/config` of that repository. In general, settings from there override the ones from your home directory, which override those from the system configuration.

In Eclipse, do this:

- Type "git repo" into Quick Access to open the *Git Repositories* view
- On your repository, open the context menu and select *Properties*
- Click *Add Entry...* and enter the values as above

Alternatively, the same can be done via preferences > Team > Git > Configuration.